# Вход и выход на сайте

Tags: php, html

Привет всем. Не знаю, что за напасть. Написал фрагмент данного вида позволяющий менять форму в зависимости от присутствия пользователя. Пересмотрел кучу примеров в сети, и везде у всех данная композиция работает. У меня же проблема, работает либо вход либо выход, в зависимости от условия. Хотя все остальное работает, и выводя отдельно кнопку на "logout.php" сессия без проблем закрывается, но форма остается неподвижной. Где ошибаюсь?

```html
<form action="login.php" method="post"><center>
    <?php if($_SESSION['status']!="login") { ?> 
        <label>Логин:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login"></input><br>
        <label>Пароль:</label><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></input><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter"><br>
        <button formaction="registration.php">Регистрация</button></center>
    <?php  } else if ($_SESSION['status']=="login") { ?>
        <label>Добро пожаловать,<? echo " ".$_SESSION['name']." ".$_SESSION['surname']."!" ?> </label>
        <button formaction=logout.php>Выход</button>
    <?php  } ?>      
</form>
```

Comment: Для начала можно удалить  `if ($_SESSION['status']=="login")`. `http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formaction.asp`  Не во всех браузерах работрает `formaction`!.

Comment: Так же `center` не всегда закрывается а только когда нету сессии

Comment: С **formaction** у меня проблем нет. Нет смены формы выхода на форму входа при выходе из сессии. Да,точно. По **center** только внимание обратил.

Comment: тогда содержимое logout.php в студию!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему сам. Проверив условие через **!=true** и **!=false**. Теперь все отлажено работает.

Comment: $var != true и $var != false лучше заменить на более простое выражение !$var. С булевыми значениями обычно не принято сравнивать.

Comment: Кстати как вариант! Опробовал, все работает так же отлажено и в этом виде.